# Python: preprocess data in a format to mine for Association rules and frequent itemsets (apriori/SPADE)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the format consisting of 245 rows and 2 columns in which the column **Unique** consists of lists :

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'TC': ['101', '102', '103'], 
                    'Unique': [[189,113,213,201,125,211],   
                               [206,268,446,149,104,166],
                               [163,103,113,166,800,101]]}))
```

i want to iterate through the dataframe and explode the lists in **Unique** into separate columns so that i can run some  frequent itemset mining algorithm on my data.
**expected output**

```
TC     0   1    2    3    4     5

101   189  113  213  201  125  211 
102   206  268  446  149  104  166
103   163  103  113  166  800  101
```

Also, If possible i want to create a **nested list** of all unique field in sequential order:

**ie**

```
unique=[[189,113,213,201,125,211 ],[206,268,446,149,104,166],[163,103,113,166,800,101]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create a nested list :

```py
nested_list = list(df['Unique'])

print(nested_list)
# Output:
[[189, 113, 213, 201, 125, 211],
 [206, 268, 446, 149, 104, 166],
 [163, 103, 113, 166, 800, 101]]
```

to create your desired table simply create a new DataFrame from this nested list and add the column TC as index column

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(nested_list)  # fills df with each nested list as a new column
x['TC'] = df['TC']             # add TC column
x = x.set_index('TC')          # set TC column as index to make it show as first column

print(x)

# Output:
       0    1    2    3    4    5
TC                               
101  189  113  213  201  125  211
102  206  268  446  149  104  166
103  163  103  113  166  800  101 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one issue though,  if i try to run Apriori on the nested_list.
y=pd.DataFrame(apriori(nested_list))
I get the TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Please open a new question for this, I am not familiar with apriori

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.DataFrame({'TC': ['101', '102', '103'],
                    'Unique': [[189,113,213,201,125,211],
                               [206,268,446,149,104,166],
                               [163,103,113,166,800,101]]}))


df[list(range(len(df.Unique[0])))] = pd.DataFrame(df.Unique.values.tolist(), index= df.index)
df = df.drop('Unique', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    TC    0    1    2    3    4    5
0  101  189  113  213  201  125  211
1  102  206  268  446  149  104  166
2  103  163  103  113  166  800  101
```

Comment: you can replace `['0','1','2','3','4','5']` with `np.arange(6)` or even `np.arange(len(df.Unique[0]))`